# I want to use :username in the field instead of :user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, messaging

I am beginner in ruby on rails. I am building a forum application. In addition to post and comments on posts, I want the private messaging system in the application. The message should be sent to the desired user("only recipient can see the message"). For that I generated a model **Notification** having *message* as a column. 
**Notification Model**

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**Notification Migration**

```
class CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :notifications do |t|
      t.text :message  
      t.integer :recipient_id, class_name: "User"
      t.timestamps null: false    
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true    
    end   
  end
end
```

**Notification Controller**

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController


    def index
        @notifications = Notification.all.order("created_at DESC")

    end

    def new
        @notification = @notification.new
    end

    def create
        @notification = @notification.new notification_params
        if @notification.save
            redirect_to(:controller => "posts", :action => "index")
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    private

    def notification_params
        params.require(:notification).permit(:message, :user_id, :recipient_id)
    end

end
```

**Notification#new** view

```
<%= form_for(:notification, :url => {:action => "create"}) do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field(:message, :placeholder => "Enter your message") %>
    <%= f.number_field(:recipient_id, :placeholder => "Enter the recipient") %>
    <%= f.submit("send message") %>

<% end %>
```

This is working. But I have to enter the :user_id in the :recepient_id field. What I want is I want to fill the field with username(recipient name) instead of filling :recipient_id. Please help me. I appreciate your answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you think about using the Drop down list? - Refer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Comment: As the users are more in number (100's may be 1000's) it is difficult for users to search. And the user can only send the message if he knows the username). Can u help me on this?

Comment: In that case, I think you can use text field and collect user name, and in your controller lookup the Recipient by name.

Comment: Can u please post that in answer? I didn't understand as I am beginner in rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion are as below - I have not tested this code, hence, use this code for illustration.

Use text field for recipient identification so that user can enter recipient name:

```
<%= f.text_field(:recipient_name, :placeholder => "Enter the recipient") %>
```

And in your controller, update `notification_params` to allow `recipient_name` param.

```
def notification_params
    params.require(:notification).permit(:message, :user_id, :recipient_name)
end
```

Also, in `create` method, you can look up the Recipient:

```
def create

    # Look up user corresponding to the name.
    u = User.find_by(name: params[:recipient_name])

    # Add recipient_id to params
    notification_params = notification_params.merge({recipient_id: u.id})

    @notification = @notification.new notification_params
    if @notification.save
        redirect_to(:controller => "posts", :action => "index")
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```